# Can't find IIS management console in Windows 7 Home Basic Edition

Tags: windows-7, iis

I tried to install the IIS 7 Manager in Windows 7 Home Basic Edition by downloading the executable file from the below link:

> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=32c54c37-7530-4fc0-bd20-177a3e5330b7&displaylang=en

Before installation starts it prompts something like:

> You haven't installed the IIS management console. Please install the IIS
>   management console in the Windows turn on/off feature.

When I go through the Windows turn on/off feature, I didn't find IIS management console there, but it showed IIS and IIS Hostable Web Core were already installed (already checked these check boxes).

Any suggestions to get IIS Manager on this Windows 7 edition?

Answer (score 2):

It's a couple of levels deep, you need to expand the tree a little.

[image: IIS]